# Implement Command Pattern Effectively

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

Initial code:

```
public void updateState(final int state)
{
    preSet();
    itsState = state;
    postSet();
}
public void setTitle(final String title)
{
    preSet();
    itsTitle = title;
    postSet();
}
```

After my Command Pattern Implementation:

```
public void updateState(final int state)
{
  CallableManager.doInTransaction(new Callable<Void>()
  {
     @Override
     public Void execute()
     {
       itsHiddenNodes = hiddenNodes;
       return null;
     }
  });
}
public void setTitle(final String title)
{
  CallableManager.doInTransaction(new Callable<Void>()
  {
     @Override
     public Void execute()
     {
       itsTitle = title;
       return null;
     }
  });
}
```

This interface is created for pass method as parameter.

```
private interface Callable<T>
{
    public T execute();
}
```

This class is created to manage command pattern.

```
private class CallableManager
{
    public <T> static void doInTransaction(final Callable<T> callable)
    {
        preSet();
        callable.execute();
        postSet();
    }
}
```

As you see, implementing command pattern does not look like very effective at least as line of code for this example. For this example, I implement command pattern to escape from repeated code and decrease the line of code. But as a result both of them are not provided for this example. Please give me some advice. How can I use command pattern effectively?

Comment: Patterns are not about reducing lines of code. Why are you trying to use this pattern here?

Comment: I know but I expect at least decrease the repeat of codes.

Comment: I'd suggest you review [this primer](https://www.baeldung.com/java-command-pattern). I think it might answer your question.

Comment: @Sha and that is happening. Now the logic to `doInTransaction` is in a single place, if you need to change it you'll have to change it in a single place.

Comment: Having a pattern without knowing what you want to achieve with it makes it hard to come up with a proper implementation. What is the idea behind `updateState` and `setTitle` ?

Comment: @Sha : Your implementation looks fine to me. For better readability, please look at the answer provided by jaco0646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda can reduce the code duplication considerably. Also, [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) seems like a more appropriate interface than [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), since you are not returning a value.

```
public class MainJava {
    private int state;
    private String title;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MainJava mj = new MainJava();
        mj.setState(42);
        mj.setTitle("My Title");
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        doInTransaction(() -> this.state = state);
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        doInTransaction(() -> this.title = title);
    }

    private void doInTransaction(Runnable runnable) {
        preSet();
        runnable.run();
        postSet();
    }

    private void preSet() {
        System.out.println("preset");
    }
    private void postSet() {
        System.out.println("post-set");
    }
}
```